# What happens when two variables of a double integral turn out to be related

Tags: integration

Say I want to evaluate

$$\int f(x,y)dxdy$$

but I find out $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ Does this imply I must have done something wrong to begin with? If not, what is the meaning of this?

Comment: The integral is an area integral, whilst $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ specifies a curve, so the area integral doesn't make sense. Perhaps if you showed us the question in which it appears light may be shed.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate y to the appropriate boundary and then x over the full range.

$$\int_{a}^{b}dx\int_{0}^{\sqrt {1-x^2}}dy f(x,y)$$

Comment: @grdgfgr The question definitely needs clarification. Does this look okay?